# filtering list inside forEach with multiple conditions

Tags: c#

I have created c# method to filter list of students based on certain conditions.

I created `filteredstudents` list first to populate it after applying initial filter condition on students list.

Then i created another list `filteredstudentsWithUnits` to populate after applying filters on `filteredstudents`

I tried to make it shorter like using single list but couldn't come find the way.

Can someone suggest because i will have additional filter conditions so i really don't want to create multiple lists.

```
private List<StudentDTO> _validateStudents(List<StudentDTO> students)
{   
    List<StudentDTO> filteredstudents = new List<StudentDTO>();
    foreach (StudentDTO student in students)
    {
        if (student.age != null && student.status != "DEL")
            filteredstudents.Add(student);
        else
            _log("create log");
    }

    List<StudentDTO> filteredstudentsWithUnits = new List<StudentDTO>();
    foreach (StudentDTO student in filteredstudents)
    {
        bool valid = true;
        foreach (SubjectTypes subjectType in student.SubjectTypes)
        {
            string value1 = subjectType.SubjectItem.Select(x => x.value1).First();
            Guid StId = _context.Items.Where(x => x.Name == value1).FirstOrDefault();

            if (StId != null)
                valid = true;
            else
            {
                valid = false;
                _log("create log");
            }
        }
        if (valid)
            filteredstudentsWithUnits.Add(student);
    }
    return filteredstudentsWithUnits;
}
```

Comment: Linq is a great thing, you should check it out

Answer (score 2):

If i read your code correctly you could use this short LINQ query:

```
List<StudentDTO> filteredstudentsWithUnits = students
    .Where(s => s.age != null && s.status != "DEL")
    .Where(s => !_context.Items
        .Any(x => s.SubjectTypes
            .SelectMany(t => t.SubjectItem.Select(si => si.value1))
            .Contains(x.Name)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: That seems really nice and short version but only issue "I will lose logging for each condition not satisfying". Basically i would like log some info for each condition not satisfying.

Comment: Have a look at linq except. It will give you those not fulfilling the conditions @Tim wrote. Then you can log them.